# Gui tool for viewing full history of a file, including moved or renamed files

Tags: linux, git, version-control, revision-history

Is there a GUI tool for git on Linux that can show the history of a specific file, including commits and actual diff/changes? A full history of the file, including the history before renaming/moving.

If no, any way to see this history if I know the file path/name before the rename/move?

If no, is there a way to do this without a GUI tool?

So far I've tried to use `gitk --follow <file-path>` but that doesn't show every commit and it doesn't show the diff before the rename/move.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: you could try to use `tig` to do that: https://jonas.github.io/tig/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `--follow`, `gitk` accepts the same options `git log` does, so you can explore the `-C` and `-M` options to affect the heuristics Git uses to detect renames/copies.

As to the following questions,

1. Just use `git log --follow [-C[n]] [-M[n]] -- path/to/file`
2. It's possible to have this diff generated manually:

   ```
    $ git diff oldcommit:an/old/path nwcommit:a/new/path
   ```

   …which can be used to diff the contents of a file which was renamed
   to "a/new/path" in commit `newcommit` from "an/old/path" as recorded (last)
   in the commit `oldcommit`.

---

*Update* from 2022-03-17:

`gitk` also has a useful "Show origin of this line" command in its context menu which one can pop up on any line of the displayed diff.
It's useful to "drill down" through the history to find out which commit introduced a particular bit of code.